# Jquery same button different functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

The thing that I want is `<button>` with an ID of `btn` to change color when clicked. Then I want it to change the ID of the button and the same `<button>` with a different ID to do another function when clicked.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mpxfmwvg/

```js
var btn = $("#btn");
var btn2 = $("#btn2");
var one = $(".one");

btn.on("click",function(){
    one.css("background-color","black");
    btn.attr("id","btn2").text("Buton2");
    
});
btn2.on("click",function(){
    one.css("background-color","green");
    btn2.attr("id","btn").text("Button");
});
```

```css
.one{
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one"></div>
<button id="btn">Button</button>
```

Comment: I think your best bet would be to actually have 2 different buttons, and just toggle `display: none` between them.

Comment: OK, wait a minute... what you actually want is a single button to toggle two functions?

Comment: Single button to act as two different buttons , switching id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind the event with `$(document)` as it is not static.

```
var btn = $("#btn");
var btn2 = $("#btn2");
var one = $(".one");

$(document).on("click","#btn",function(){

  one.css("background-color","black");
  btn.attr("id","btn2").text("Buton2");

});
$(document).on("click","#btn2",function(){

  one.css("background-color","green");
  $(this).attr("id","btn").text("Button");
});
```

[SEE Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mpxfmwvg/6/)

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
var btn = $("#btn");

var one = $(".one");

btn.on("click",function(){

one.css("background-color","black");
btn.attr("id","btn2").on( "click", function(){

one.css("background-color","green");
btn2.attr("id","btn").text("Button");
});
});
```

Hope this be of some help

Happy Learning

Answer (score 0):

You assume changing an element ID would link with the code executed at load time where some element was searched for by that ID. The btn2 is empty when instantiated. Code that runs afterward will never come back in time and fix this, You should consider a more 'event-driven' approach to javascript. Think that the .on('click') has consecuences after it has been clicked, not when you write the code ;)

```js
var btn = $("#btn");
var btn2 = $("#btn2"); // this does not exist
var one = $(".one");

var clickTwo = function(){
  alert('CLICK 2!');
  one.css("background-color","black");
  btn.attr("id","btn2").text("Buton2");// this does not retroactively create the #btn2 element, 
  //much less the btn2 reference
}

var clickOne = function(){
  one.css("background-color","black");
  $(this).attr("id","btn2").text("Buton2");
  $(this).on('click', clickTwo)
  alert('btn2 does not actually exist: length of jQuery selection is ' + btn2.size());
}

btn.one("click", clickOne);
```

```css
.one{
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one"></div>
<button id="btn">Button</button>
```

Comment: it is calling click2 all the times

Comment: The first time it runs clickOne. In turn clickOne sets the click handler to be clickTwo, and this sticks on the button. It does not remove/replace itself. Click will be handled by clickTwo, unless clickTwo does not remove itself, or someone else calls btn.off('click'/*, clickTwo*/);

Answer (score 0):

This example covers every case of toggling two functions or values by alternating a single HTMLElement's object property value (1,0,1,...) using Bitwise XOR operator `^`.

```js
function aFn(el){
   $(el).text("AAAAAAA");
}
function bFn(el){
   $(el).text("BBBBBBB");
}

function tog(){
   var io = this.io ^= 1; // 1/0 Toggler; El Obj Property
   // Example using the `io` with Ternary Operator
   $(".one").css("background-color", io ? "black" : "green");
   // Example using `io` to toggle two functions
   [aFn, bFn][io]( this );  
   // If you need to toggle the ID:
   this.id = io ? "btn2" : "btn"
}

// Incredible, even if we change ID all you need is:
$("#btn").on('click', tog);
```

```css
.one{
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    background-color:red;
}
#btn{}
#btn2{padding:10px; border:4px solid gold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one"></div>
<button id="btn">Button</button>
```